# LibGDX 3D: offset camera without changing perspective

Tags: 3d, libgdx, viewport

I'm trying to render a 3D scene and add an offset to the whole viewport after projection.

For example, you can see here how the second image is the same as the first one but with an offset, and the third image has the cube at an offset aswell but it has a different perspective:
[image]

I saw that the `Camera` class has a `project` method that receives `viewportX` and `viewportY` parametrs which seem to do what I'm trying to achieve:

```
public Vector3 project (Vector3 worldCoords, float viewportX, float viewportY, float viewportWidth, float viewportHeight) {
    worldCoords.prj(combined);
    worldCoords.x = viewportWidth * (worldCoords.x + 1) / 2 + viewportX;
    worldCoords.y = viewportHeight * (worldCoords.y + 1) / 2 + viewportY;
    worldCoords.z = (worldCoords.z + 1) / 2;
    return worldCoords;
}
```

But I didn't find a way to set them when rendering and I'm not even sure if this method is relevant for the actual rendering process.

I also tried calling `glViewport(0, 100, w, h)` before drawing each frame but it seems to have no effect.

Any help would be appricited, thanks.

Comment: You'll have to be explicitly clear about what you mean by "add an offset to the whole viewport after projection", because that could be interpreted a hundred different ways.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I changed the title and added an image to explain. Hopefully it's clearer now.